# Optimal way to delete last line of file in C++

Tags: c++

I'm currently using the following code to delete the last line of a .txt file. It works, but it's very slow. What could I do to optimize this bit of code?

```
string line; 
vector<string> lines;
std::ifstream inputStream("example.txt");

while (getline(inputStream,line)) {
    lines.push_back(line);
}
inputStream.close();

std::fstream outputStream("example.txt", ios::out | ios::trunc);
if (outputStream.is_open())
{
    for (int i=0; i < lines.size()-2; i++)
    {
        outputStream << lines[i] << "\n";
    }
    outputStream.close();
}
```

Comment: I think the std::cout is the most expensive operation here.

Comment: writing the file data at all is usually completely redundant.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the size of the file, you may find it faster to actually read the file from the end (in chunks), and save the position of the last line. Then, you could just copy a part of the file starting from the beginning, to the desired position. That way, you won't have to do so many IO operations.

So the actual algorithm would be something like:

1. Open file
2. Position the read pointer at the end-*chunkSize*
3. Read *chunkSize* bytes of data
4. If there is a line break, store the *position*, else return to 3.
5. Copy the contents from the start to *position*

Comment: Blockwise backwards scan. Simple enough, and likely much faster than forward scan for large file.

Comment: Didn't even know there's a term for that. Guess I reinvented the wheel once again :) Thanks for the notice @RichardPlunkett !

Answer (score 3):

There are OS-dependent functions for changing a file's size.

In the Unix world, use truncate(): http://linux.die.net/man/2/truncate

In the Windows world, use SetEndOfFile(): http://www.google.com/search?btnI=1&q=msdn+SetEndOfFile

Both techniques require gaining an OS file handle and dinking with the file that way. If you wish to do this, I would write a function that takes a file name and a new size that does it.

This just leave the problem of finding the new size. I think scan from the back has the potential to be more efficient than a scan from the front, but that's really an exercise for the reader either way.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to buffer the entire file in memory. Instead, you could write to a second, temporary file while reading the original. Once the second file is written and the first file is closed, the temporary can be renamed to become the primary file (on UNIXes you could also `remove()` the primary file once it is opened and directly write to it, opening it for input after it was `remove()`d):

```
{
    std::ifstream in("example.txt");
    std::ofstream out("example.tmp");
    // some error checking...
    std::string line;
    std::getline(line);
    for (std::string tmp; std::getline(tmp); line.swap(tmp)) {
        out << line << '\n';
    }
    if (!out.close()) {
        // seems the output couldn't be written: deal with it somehow
    }
}
std::rename("example.tmp", "example.txt");
```

Comment: A simple non-buffered solution. Definitely better than the original in most ways. Has minor issues any user should be aware of (mainly that it fails slightly differently and for slightly different reasons). Eg. this will fail if you are out of diskspace, while the original may not. Also, if this fails due to example.txt being non-writable, this will leave a tmp file lying around - possibly a good thing.